# Customize tables using Matplotlib - colorization and fonts

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use Matplotlib to create tables to be exported to a pdf.

I struggle with the following.

1. To in a automated fashion create a list of list for the colorization of the cells. The first columns should be white, the second green, and so on.
2. To set an alpha value for rows I color with green, to increase transparancy.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Z', 'S', 'H'],
                  'Category':['A', 'A', 'A'],
                  'Number':[2,1,3],
                  'P':[0,0,0]})

col_col=[]
blue = '#00005A'
green = '#95C13E'

for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    col_col.append(blue)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Arial'
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

# Can I use a for loop to create the list of list colo in smart way?
colo = [["w",green,"w", green],["w",green,"w", green],["w",green,"w", green]] 

table=ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center', 
         colColours=col_col, 
         cellColours=colo)

table=ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center', 
         colColours=col_col, 
         cellColours=colo)

for i, j in zip(table.properties()['celld'], table.properties()['children']):
    if i[0]==0:
        j.get_text().set_color('white')
        j.get_text().set_weight('bold')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to convert the green color you are specifying to RGBA format and specify the transparency.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors　#import

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':\['Z', 'S', 'H'\],
                  'Category':\['A', 'A', 'A'\],
                  'Number':\[2,1,3\],
                  'P':\[0,0,0\]})

col_col=\[\]
blue = '#00005A'
green = '#95C13E'
green = mcolors.to_rgba(green, alpha=0.5)　#update and set alpha value

for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    col_col.append(blue)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams\['font.family'\] = 'Arial'
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

# Can I use a for loop to create the list of list colo in smart way?
colo = \[\["w",green,"w", green\],\["w",green,"w", green\],\["w",green,"w", green\]\] 

table=ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center', 
         colColours=col_col, 
         cellColours=colo)

for i, j in zip(table.properties()\['celld'\], table.properties()\['children'\]):
    if i\[0\]==0:
        j.get_text().set_color('white')
        j.get_text().set_weight('bold')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]